# paypal transaction history creates an extra recurring payment

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox

I'm using the paypal recurring gem:

https://github.com/fnando/paypal-recurring

for a ruby on rails application

Here's a selected portion of my code:

```
 def make_recurring

    process :request_payment

    if @plan
      create_units
      process :create_recurring_profile, period: @plan.recurring, amount: (@plan.price), frequency: 1, start_at: Time.zone.now        
    end
  end


 def process(action, options={})
    not_recurring_amount =  @cart.total_price  
    not_recurring_amount += 19.95 if @plan #add activation price for first payment

    options = options.reverse_merge(
      token: @order.paypal_payment_token,
      payer_id: @order.paypal_customer_token,
      description: "Your product total is below",
      amount: not_recurring_amount.round(2),
      currency: "USD"
    )

    response = PayPal::Recurring.new(options).send(action)
    raise response.errors.inspect if response.errors.present?
    response
  end
```

Essentially, a user buys a product and gets charged 239.95. Then a user buys a plan for the product with a one time activation and gets charged 33.95. Those are both one time payments. Then when they buy the plan, they also get charged a 14.95 recurring monthly charge for that airtime plan. Everything seems to work but I notice in my paypal sandbox account another recurring charge that is blank:

[image]

Why is that blank charge happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not an actual charge, its just a record of the profile being created.  You have to first create a profile, before it can be charged.  This is reflected in the PayPal account as you are seeing.

Comment: So is what I have done correct? I'm not sure if the results are what I am expecting.

Comment: What you have done looks correct.  However, regarding the one time set up charge of 33.95, you can have this be apart of the profile where it charges this just once, but does not include it as part of the regular recurring profile chages.  When you create the profile, you woudl just set this amount using the variable INITAMT if your using NVP.  You can also use the variable FAILEDINITAMTACTION to set the action.