# cancel paypal recurring payment with instant payment notification

Tags: paypal, paypal-ipn

From my gathering of several stackoverflow posts, when a user cancels a paypal recurring payment, an instant payment notification is sent to a specified url set up in the IPN settings. But what I cannot gather is what data is sent to this url in the query string. I came across this link:

```
https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=p/acc/ipn-subscriptions-outside
```

It provides a list of variables which I assume are sent as part of the query string sent with the url specified in IPN settings. If this is true, then that means I know this notification is a cancel notification, because the txn_type value will be "subscr_cancel".

However, I still need to know what recurring plan is actually being canceled. Hence, I need to know the recurring profile token in order to access it as a variable in query string.

Just to give you an idea of what I am trying to do here, here is some sample code:

```
def notify_url
if params[:txn_type] == "subscr_cancel"
  item_id = Order.where(paypal_recurring_profile_token: params[:recurring_profile_token]).unit_id_for_plan
  agent_host = CONFIG["agent_#{Rails.env}"]["host"]
  agent_port = CONFIG["agent_#{Rails.env}"]["port"]

 url = "http://#{agent_host}:#{agent_port}/home/deactivate?item_id=#{item_id}"
 begin
    resp = Net::HTTP.get(URI.parse(url))
    resp = JSON.parse(resp)
    puts "resp is: #{resp}"
    true
  rescue => error
    raise "Error: #{error}"
  end  

  if resp["status"] == "success"
    true
  end

end    
end
```

all I need to know is if txn_type will be equal to subscr_cancel when a notification is sent for a cancellation of recurring billing? @PP_MTS_Chad already confirmed that recurring_payment_id is included. I just need to know if txn_type is included as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When a profile is canceled, in your IPN POST you will get back the variable `recurring_payment_id` which will have the profile of the profile being canceled.

```
Array
(
    [amount3] => 69.95
    [address_status] => confirmed
    [recur_times] => 5
    [subscr_date] => 07:31:10 May 17, 2013 PDT
    [payer_id] => EW4KQ9CQX45F6
    [address_street] => 1 Main St
    [mc_amount3] => 69.95
    [charset] => KOI8-R
    [address_zip] => 95131
    [first_name] => MTS
    [reattempt] => 1
    [address_country_code] => US
    [address_name] => MTS Testing
    [notify_version] => 3.7
    [subscr_id] => I-628HEBW1V99M
    [payer_status] => verified
    [business] => chad@x.com
    [address_country] => United States
    [address_city] => San Jose
    [verify_sign] => AQ3T0Omh4bXNzomBbYUO2LL1dphyAiWU5Sa7wpw8spAU-Pb1YFnm-mig
    [payer_email] => mts_us_per@ccaples.com
    [last_name] => Testing
    [address_state] => CA
    [receiver_email] => chad@x.com
    [recurring] => 1
    [txn_type] => subscr_cancel
    [item_name] => Alice's Weekly Digest
    [mc_currency] => USD
    [item_number] => DIG Weekly
    [residence_country] => US
    [test_ipn] => 1
    [period3] => 6 M
    [ipn_track_id] => 54b49fde502a4
)
```

Comment: Is :txn_type with value "subscr_cancel" sent back as well?

Comment: Yes, you will get this back.  I have added an example of an IPN POST to my original answer, that I received back when a profile was cancelled.

Comment: In that IPN POST, I dont see recurring_payment_id.

Comment: It is subscr_id for this particular post since it was for a subscription instead of a recurring payment.  Just for clarification are you using subsriptions or recurring payments, you have mentioned both.

Comment: I am using both. User buys product one-time payment. Once they buy product, they buy a plan. The plan is done with recurring payments.

Comment: I had this question here that showed how it works, some payments are recurring and some are not: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16473088/paypal-transaction-history-creates-an-extra-recurring-payment When the request comes in I need to make sure its a recurring payment and that its a cancellation of recurring payment, and that I have access to the recurring_payment_id.

Comment: If you are using both then, depending on if its a recurring payment or a subscription, the variable name will be slightly different.  It will either be subscr_id or recurring_payment_id depending on which it is, and it will give you the profile id of the profile being cancelled.

Comment: will txn_type equal subscr_cancel in both cases?

Comment: all I need to know is if txn_type will be equal to subscr_cancel when a notification is sent for a cancellation of recurring billing? You already confirmed that recurring_payment_id is included. I just need to know if txn_type is included as well.

Comment: Yes, transaction type should be included as well.  You can run test transactions using the sandbox, and see the results of the IPN for the different causes.

Comment: Yes it is included but under the name recurring_payment_profile_cancel not subcr_cancel

Comment: The difference is based on what type of recurring transaction you are testing with/using.  The "recurring_payment_profile_cancel" is for recurring payments and the "subscr_cancel" is for subscriptions.